# Return only the value needed with preg_match

Tags: php, preg-match

In a PHP script i perform a parsing of html document like that :

```
    $patternSearch = '`\[my_tag](.+)\[/my_tag]`';
    preg_match($patternSearch, $doc, $matches1);
    echo ''.$matches1['0'].'';
```

problem is in the return i have all the string : `[my_tag]lorem ipsum 123456[/my_tag]`

I just want the value inside tags, how to correct that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, to get the value inside, you can do this

```
echo $matches1[1];
```

And if you want to get all the value inside all your tag (if you have more than one tag).

```
preg_match_all($patternSearch, $doc, $match);
print_r($match[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php 
$doc = "[my_tag]lorem ipsum 123456[/my_tag]";
$patternSearch = '`\[my_tag](.*?)\[/my_tag]`';    
preg_match($patternSearch, $doc, $matches1);
echo ''.$matches1[1].'';
?>
```